# All the guns in the game shoot at the same time when I only want the gun that I'm holding to shoot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

My problem is that when I'm holding a gun and shoot it, all the other guns on the floor start shooting as well. How do I make it so that only the gun that I'm holding with the mouse can shoot?

You pick up the gun with the mouse left click, and you shoot with right click

My pickup code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool Pressed = false;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Pressed = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
    }
 
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Pressed = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        if(Pressed)
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            transform.position = mousePos;
        }
    }
}
```

My gun code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour{

       public Transform firePoint;
       public float fireRate = 15f;
       public GameObject bulletPrefab;
       public Transform  MuzzleFlashPrefab;

       private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;
       
   
    
    void Update() {


        

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f/fireRate;
            Shoot();
              
        }
    }


     void Shoot ()
    {
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
         Transform clone = Instantiate (MuzzleFlashPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as Transform;
       clone.parent = firePoint;
       float size = Random.Range (0.02f, 0.025f);
       
       clone.localScale = new Vector3 (size, size, size);
       Destroy (clone.gameObject, 0.056f);
    }

 
}
```

and my bullet code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bulet : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    
    public float speed = 40f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

  
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of letting the weapon control when it is fired rather do it in the player and call a method `Shoot` on the weapon you are currently holding.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag in your Weapon, something called liked `pickedUp`, and toggle it when the weapon is picked up/dropped. Then in your Weapon's Update function, check if you should process Inputs for that weapon based on its picked up state. If its not picked up, there is no need to check if it should fire a bullet or not.